HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225dw Ubuntu 24.04 driver
HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225dw has a Sourceforge hplip driver but this does not yet support 24.04
 Robert Smith - 2024-08-20 I managed to get a minimal setup to work on Ubuntu 24.04 by running python3 install.py --no-qt4
from the hplip-3.24.4 directory and only installing the driver in the custom install.
I have tried the above with no success.  Has anyone on this list made the current hplip work on 24.04?  If not, how does one configure a "standard in the distro" CUPS system to work with an HP printer, in particular HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225dw?  Although this printer also is a scanner, I am not expecting that functionality to work -- just printing, preferably with "graphics" and different fonts.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Your comment refers to hplip to the Rescue .  Before I tried the current Sourceforge hplip method (please see my question), I did sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui but that did not seem to work (including hp-setup and the rest in the answer you found).  If this had worked, I would not have tried the Sourceforge route.  Is there a method to absolutely purge (fully remove) all existing instances of hplip hplib-gui both form the Sourceforge and any Ubuntu distro installs, and then start over from the apt instructions above? I need a "method" that has been tested on 24.04.
